# Deleting and Inserting Elements in Array

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Example {

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        String [] wombology;
        wombology = new String[3];
        wombology[0] = "History of Wombology";
        wombology[1] = "Why Wombology";
        wombology[2] = "Wombology and Me";


        Random book = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Scanner choice = new Scanner(System.in);
        String yourChoice;

        do {

            System.out.println("Press enter for random book");
            yourChoice = choice.nextLine();         

            if(yourChoice.equals("")) {

                System.out.println(wombology[randomizer.nextInt(3)]);
                System.out.println();

            }

            if(yourChoice == "EXIT") {

                break;

            }

        } while(!yourChoice.equals("EXIT"));
    }

}
```

- How could I take out a "book" from the array once chosen randomly?
- How could I put back in said "book" later back into the array?

*Example: "History of Wombology" is randomly chosen and is taken out.*

*The next random selection should NOT include "History of Wombology" until it is put back in.*

*Meaning only "Why Wombology" and "Wombology and Me" should be the only possible choices.*

Comment: yourChoice == "EXIT" why don't use .equals

Comment: Once an array is created, its size cannot change.  Try looking up [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) which will make your job easy.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that this is homework and an `ArrayList` is not possible.  And I don't want to give a full, detailed answer.

One option might be to create a parallel array, `boolean isCheckedOut[]`, and track your books there.

Comment: Actually it is not homework, I just want to use the code above with improvements to "shuffle" the monsters in Arkham Horror. That der Dhole is a killer I tells ya.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manage the array yourself. That means you need to know the real size of the array and the filled size. This is because once the array is created the size cannot change.

If you delete an object from the array you need to shift the adjacent elements towards that position.

For example, your array looks like this:

```
[A|B|C|D|E|F]

allocatedArraySize = 6
currentSize = 6
```

If you delete `C` which is at position `2` then you must shift `D, E, F` to the left. You could also make the last position null.

```
[A|B|D|E|F|null]

allocatedArraySize = 6
currentSize = 5
```

---

To insert, simply use this:

```
// Check Array is not full.
if(currentSize != allocatedArraySize)
{
   // Then add your object to the last position in the array.
   array[currentSize] = obj;
   // Increment the index.
   currentSize++;
}

else
{
   // Don't allow insertion.
   // Or create a new-bigger-array; 
   // then copy all elements of the full array into it.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to "define" an action for "taking out a book" on the technical level. I can image two possibilities for this

- setting the array content at the specific position to `null`
- setting the array content at the specific position to an empty string

As the title of most books consists of one or more letters, the empty string-proposal seems also to be valid.

The second task (putting a book back into the array) can be handled in a similar way. Here you have to find an empty place (an array position with an empty string/null as content) and assign the name of the book to it.

Concerning the randomizer and not allowing already removed books: you can use the aforementioned condition to rerun the randomizer, i.e until an non-empty string/not-null element is found in the array. If you found one, it is a valid choice. But beware, if you removed all books, the randomizer would never stop running (because it finds only invalid choices and hence never returns). Here you can use an additional check condition: if the array only consists of empty strings/ null values, it is not required to run the randomizer.

Hope that helps...